# Closing questions as too local

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This question has been around for 6 months without response from the asker:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23906/gmail-via-web-is-ok-but-via-gnus-is-not-working-why-and-how-to-fix

It seems likely that the source of the problem is something particular about the posters environment, and the lack of detail in the question makes it unlikely to be of any value to other users.

I have vague memories of a 'too local' reason for closing a question, which I thought might apply here. However, that's not currently an option for close votes. What's the best response here? I'm tempted to flag for closing with either "Not clear what you're asking" or "too broad", but it's not a great fit for either of those categories.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of these sorts of questions where the problem is probably due to something that's not mentioned in the question, but someone might make a good guess based on the symptoms, or offer a generic diagnosis guide. I'm reluctant to close these outright, but when the question has been around for months, it's pretty unlikely that a useful answer will ever come. So I've closed the question.

“Unclear what you're asking” applies. The question lacks a lot of information about the asker's environment — what they actually put in their init file, their operating system, their network setup, etc.

There used to be a close reason called “too localized”, but it wouldn't have applied here: it was intended to apply to questions that couldn't have applied to anyone else. It wouldn't be applicable here because the issue with this question is that we have no way to know what the problem is. It could turn out to be a widely applicable problem, but we don't have enough information to know that. That close reason was often misused and [was consequently removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons).

For cases where this close reason would have been useful, such as “there's a typo on line 3”, you can use “off-topic” and enter a custom message explaining why you're voting to close. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) has a preset close reason under “off-topic” labeled

> Questions describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed) are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers.

This would apply here as well, but we don't encounter the case often enough to make it worth adding a preset.