# Not reproducible or was caused by a typo

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Could we acquire Stack Overflow's **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo** community-specific reason for voting to close a question?

The description is:

> While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

It's not too uncommon for users to post problems which turn out to be so very specific to their own Emacs config that the chances of the question ever being of any use to another person seem absolutely minimal.

[Closing questions as too local](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470) is almost a duplicate, but I think S.O. has probably revised the wording since then, so I think this is worth revisiting.